# How to pass pointer vector to function c++

Tags: c++, file, c++11, object, vector

Essentially I want to use a `std::vector<>` to hold all of the objects to draw to the screen (opengl). I want to read all of the new models from the .obj file and input these new objects into my `std::vector<>`. Right now the way I have it implemented is through passing the `std::vector<>` into my function for inserting each new model into the `std::vector<>`. I am pretty flexible as to the implementation except for the declaration of the `std::vector<>` holding all of the objects.

file/model loader:

```
void glc::ShapeLoader::load(const char* path, std::vector<CustomShape*>* shape) {
    file = fopen(path, "r");
    fileName = path;
    char line[1024];
    while (fscanf(file, "%s", line) != EOF) {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
        CustomShape* nShape = new CustomShape;
        std::vector<GLfloat> newV;
        std::vector<GLfloat> newVN;
        std::vector<GLint> newF;
        GLfloat xf, yf, zf;
        if (strcmp(line, "o") == 0) {
            std::string name;
            fscanf(file, "%s\n", &name);
            nShape->typeName = name;
        }
        else if (strcmp(line, "v") == 0) {
            fscanf(file, "%f %f %f\n", &xf, &yf, &zf);
            std::vector<GLfloat> iv;
            iv.push_back(xf);
            iv.push_back(yf);
            iv.push_back(zf);
            nShape->vn.push_back(iv);
        }
        else if (strcmp(line, "vn") == 0) {
            fscanf(file, "%f %f %f\n", &xf, &yf, &zf);
            std::vector<GLfloat> iv;
            iv.push_back(xf);
            iv.push_back(yf);
            iv.push_back(zf);
            nShape->vn.push_back(iv);
        }
        else if (strcmp(line, "f") == 0) {
            GLint x, y, z;
            fscanf(file, "%i %i %i\n", &x, &y, &z);
            std::vector<GLint> iv;
            iv.push_back(x);
            iv.push_back(y);
            iv.push_back(z);
            nShape->f.push_back(iv);
        }
        shape->push_back(nShape);
    }
}
```

file/model loader call:

```
s1.load("../Trees.obj", &worldObjects);
```

`std::vector<>` holding all of the models:

```
std::vector<CustomShape*> worldObjects;
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I see that `s1.load("../Trees.obj", &worldObjects);` already passes a pointer to your vector to the function. What's the problem then?

Comment: @SurDin just changed it but I want to pass insert objects from an .obj file into my vector which holds all of my objects for the scene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::vector<CustomShape*> glc::ShapeLoader::load(const char* path) {

    std::vector<CustomShape*> shape_vector;
    ... do all your loading work...
    return shape_vector;
}
```

If your first thought is "but that has to make a copy of all the data because it returns by value", then put everything you think you know about returning by value away and get ready to have your mind blown.   The copies aren't really made and the vector is actually created in the memory space outside your function so the return is free.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

Even better, use

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<CustomShape>>
```

and populate it with:

```
shape_vector.emplace_back(std::make_unique<CustomShape>(...Your custom shape constructor values here...));
```

That way you don't have to take care to delete the data for each `CustomShape`, it's done automatically for you when the `vector` goes away

Comment: Everything about copy elision being awesome is true, but we can count on it (i.e. it being mandatory) only from c++17 onward. For c++ prior it's only an optimization (though a very likely one).

Comment: @StoryTeller You have to work to not get it.  It's much more important to write clear code than to worry about irrelevant parts of the standard when working on code in real life.

Comment: Not *that* hard. Complex code (like the OP's) has a tendency to tie itself in a knot as far as optimizations may go. On an unrelated note, shouldn't that `std::make_shared` be `std::make_unique`?

Comment: @StoryTeller  no idea what you're talking about.  it says make_unique.  Just reload the page and check.  see..  always did :)  (disregard that little "edited" thing...)

Comment: The IDE shows no error's until I press play. Which means it sadly does not work or I am implementing it wrong. Also I know about make_unique but I want to tackle one thing at a time

Comment: @matt2405 what error do you get when you try to compile?  Regardless of the NRVO details storyteller brought up, the code should still compile and function correctly.

Comment: a bunch of non-errors such as fscanf being unsafe and syntax error's when there is none. The one that I think is an actual error is 'CustomShape': undeclared identifier on declaring the load function

Comment: @matt2405 make sure you grab the current code -- for some reason my copy/pastes lost some `*` initially.  They should be `std::vector<CustomShape*>`

Comment: yea I noticed it when I was implementing it and changed it. the question has the updated code as it is now

Comment: @matt2405 please don't change the code in the question, as the answers no longer make sense.   You should leave the code as it originally was.

Comment: true. you are able to see the changes though but that makes sense

Comment: @matt2405, I took the liberty to rollback your edits so xaxxons answer will be in context. If you have more errors in your code, feel free to post another seperate question about them